# Is it possible to catch multiple exceptions and perform different logic upon them without using multiple catch statements?

Tags: java, exception, java-7

As to perform different logic upon the exceptions. As following:

```
catch (IOException e | IllegalArgumentException a) {

       e.doStuff();
       a.doStuff();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't make sense. When you use a **multi** catch, then you are implicitly saying: all of "these" exceptions should fall into the same bucket.

Of course, you can then do some `instanceof` if/else trees, but heck: the java way of doing that would be to have different catch statements for each one.

But, also of course, depending on context, it might be pragmatic to do something like

```
 catch(XException | YException | ZException  xyOrZ) {
   log(xyOrZ);
   handle(xyOrZ);
```

where `handle()` does some `instanceof` "switching".

Long story short: multi catch is a convenient way to enable an aspect (such as logging) that works for all exceptions. But it can get into your way regarding exception specific handling. You simply have to balance your requirements, and use that solution that *your* team finds to best fit your needs. To a certain degree, this is about *style*, and *style* questions are decided by the people working the code base.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do it that way. This is what multiple `catch` blocks *are for*.

The `|` form lets you combine different exception types in a single `catch`, but with a common variable for the exception. Its purpose is to allow unified handling of disparate exception types. But when you want *disparate* handling of disparate types, use multiple `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 3):

In short - no. Multi-catch for exceptions has been introduced to join multiple catch blocks with same logic(like logging). So you want to do a reverse engineering here.

If you want to handle each exception in a different way, then use old notation:

```
catch (IllegalArgumentException a) {
     // handle
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle 
}
```

Doing it inside of a multicatch block would require using instanceOf, which looks nasty and less readable:

```
catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException a) {
       if(a instanceof IOException) {
         ((IOException)a).doStuff();
       } else if(a instanceof IllegalArgumentException){
         ((IllegalArgumentException)a).doStuff();
       }

    }
```

Comment: What language is your second code example? In Java it is instanceof (lower case O) and a (a IOException).doStuff(); looks quite unknown to me (and my jvc).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to catch multiple Exception in same catch block and perform different logic according to Exception caught.
For Example:

```
catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
if(e instanceof IOException){
//execute logic for IOException
}
else if(e instanceof IllegalArgumentException ){
//execute logic for IllegalArgumentException 
}
}
```